# Citing with EndNote X9

Tags: interoperability, citation-management

I am trying to cite my work with EndNote X9 by using the Insert -> Citation -> Bibliographical Reference menu item, but the citation panel is empty. Before you ask, first I opened EndNote and then Mathematica v12. Attaching a .bib file is also impossible. I am so baffled. Can someone help?

[image]

[According to the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CitationManagement.html), Mathematica can interoperate with EndNote.

Comment: Anyone has solutions? I have the same problem and I can't find a good solution.

Comment: @KnifeLee So do I but seems no one answers this question.